# Codeigniter returns 404 from android if post has values

Tags: android, codeigniter

I am trying to post a json from android to a website. Previously it was working.

After days of trial and error debugging including changing laptops and using okhttp instead of http library, ive zeroin on the server itself. apparently if i use plain php it works but when i use code igniter if returns error 404.

if the android code does not include post variables then the server returns 200 ok response.

The plain php code is below

```
<html>
      <body>
         Welcome
        <?php
            echo $_POST["email"];       
        ?>
     </body>
  </html>
```

The codeigniter controller code is below

class Index extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('Index_Model','im');
    }
public function index()
{
    echo CI_VERSION;
}

public function post()
{
    echo $this->input->post('email');
}
```

}

Both version 2 and 3 of codeigniter does not work.

Android code

```
            private void test(String s) {
                MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                String url = "http://xxxxxx.co.ke/post/index.php";
                url = "http://xxxxxx.co.ke/tracker3/index/post";
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                        .add("email", "Jurassic@Park.com")
                        .add("tel", "90301171XX")
                        .add("kujichocha", s)
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();

                Call call = client.newCall(request);

                call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                        Log.d("Meds", "onFailure() Request was: " + request);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response r) throws IOException {
                        String response = r.body().string();
                        Log.d("Meds ", "onResponse(): " + response );
                    }
                });
            }
```

http://xxxxxx.co.ke/post/index.php Works

http://xxxxxx.co.ke/tracker3/index/post Returns 404

Comment: You might be calling the wrong URL in your android app, without providing  the relevant android code there's nothing we could do to help. Side note: I think you cannot name a controller "Index" try picking a different name for your controller

Comment: have you tried to change your controller name (Index to another  name)